# Get controller and action name from AuthorizationHandlerContext object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, access-control

Hi I have a custom requirement handler with accepts the `AuthorizationHandlerContext context` parameter

When i debug, i can see that the context object contains 
Context.Resources.ActionDescription.ActionName

But when writing the code i cant go beyond
Context.Resources

Seems the lower levels are not exposed. I want to get the action name and controller name that called the handler. How do i do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
var mvcContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
var descriptor = mvcContext?.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
if (descriptor != null)
{
    var actionName = descriptor.ActionName;
    var ctrlName = descriptor.ControllerName;      
}
```

Comment: How would you get the ACTUAL INSTANCE, not just the names of the action and controller?

Answer (score 4):

After upgrading to dotnet 5, the solution I was successfully using from [Carsten above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60565942/882168) stopped working. The following workaround now works for me:

```
var routeValues = (context.Resource as HttpContext).Request.RouteValues;
var controllerName = routeValues["controller"].ToString();
var actionName = routeValues["action"].ToString();
```

Note this should include some null checks etc. the above is a barebones example.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the question is tagged for [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), I wanted to add that the answer by @AdemCaglin does not work for Web API controllers. The following code works for both, API and MVC controllers:

```cs
var endpoint = context.Resource as RouteEndpoint;
var descriptor = endpoint?.Metadata?
    .SingleOrDefault(md => md is ControllerActionDescriptor) as ControllerActionDescriptor;

if (descriptor == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to retrieve current action descriptor.");

var controllerName = descriptor.ControllerName;
var actionName = descriptor.ActionName;
```